# Best Way to Accept a Different Web Service Request Format from Customer Than our Standard XML Format

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, xslt

We have a WCF IIS 7.5 web service that uses a WSDL/XSD.   So we have a standard request xml format that is used by all customers.  Now a large customer is considering using our service but wants us to accept their format and not code to our standard request format.  What are the best options for how to handle this scenario so we don't lose the customer?  Would it be to stand up a second service that all it does is accept the request and then us XSLT to translate the request into our standard format and then call our original service, wait for the response, translate the response into their format and then send it back to the customer?  Are there other good options to consider?

Comment: Look at the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  Otherwise this is not a good question for the SO format.  Consider breaking it down into code questions.

Comment: This is more of a business question as it stands. I would consider whether it is really worth it to win this customer. Is what they are wanting you to do going to fit your core business model? Is it going to cost more to win and keep this customer than the amount of profit you might earn? Perhaps you could ask this on http://pm.stackexchange.com/